# For a subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, if $U$ is $d_2$-open (Euclidean), then $U$ is $d_1$-open (Taxicab)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

I am having a little bit of trouble trying to understand what it means for a subset $U$ to be $d$-open, and how to show that subset $U$ is $d$-open if and only if $U$ is $d'$-open on another metric, say $d'$-open. In particular, I want to consider the two metrics, namely the $d_1$ metric (taxicab) and the $d_2$ metric (Euclidean) on $\mathbb{R}^2$, or for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{align*}
d_1(x, y) = \|x - y\|_1 =  |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
d_2(x, y) = \|x - y\|_2 = (|x_1 - y_1|^2 + |x_2 - y_2|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation*}
So the goal is to prove:

> If $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then $U$ is $d_1$-open if and only if $U$ is $d_2$-open.

Some advice would be really helpful and much appreciated on how to proceed.

Comment: A set is just a collection of points. You are asked to prove that for every $x\in U$ there exists $r_1\in\Bbb R$ such that $\{y\mid d_1(x,y)\lt r_1\}\subseteq U$ if and only if for every $x\in U$ there exists $r_2\in\Bbb R$ such that $\{y\mid d_2(x,y)\lt r_2\}\subseteq U$

Answer (score 1):

On a finite-dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent, so $d_1$ and $d_2$ necessarily induce the same topology. In your case,

\begin{align}
d_2(x,y)&= (|x_1 - y_1|^2 + |x_2 - y_2|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\\&\le(|x_1 - y_1|^2 +2|x_1 - y_1|\cdot|x_2 - y_2|+ |x_2 - y_2|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\&=|x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|=d_1(x, y)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
d_1(x, y) =  |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|\le2\sqrt{\frac{|x_1 - y_1|^2 + |x_2 - y_2|^2}2}=\sqrt2d_2(x,y)
\end{align}
So $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$ are equivalent norms.